# Where can I see a Mbalax performance in Dakar?

Tags: culture, activities, senegal, dakar, entertainment

I'd like to see a performance of [Mbalax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbalax), a type of dance music in Senegal incorporating modern music and traditional drumming. Is it very common? Where in the city can I go (as a tourist) to witness it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, this took some searching, as most sites just mention the artists like Youssou N'Dour.

According to the [Lonely Planet's 1000 Ultimate Experiences](http://shop.lonelyplanet.com/world/lonely-planets-1000-ultimate-experiences-1), number 687 (in the edition I looked at) is experiencing Mbalax in Dakar, Senegal.  And apparently, local and international legend Seck hosts live mbalax nights at the Kilimanjaro club, next to the Soumbedioune evening fish market.

Comment: You are amazing :)

Comment: You're very kind ;) And why do it? Because just a minute ago I read a headline on http://www.tntmagazine.com/news/world/youssou-ndour-running-for-senegal-presidency and because of your question, knew who they were talking about :)